# A way to add Multiple object operator in a condition

Tags: php, laravel, object

In PHP, is there a way to correspond multiple object operator to check a certain condition

For example

```
if( !empty($this->user()->city && !empty($this->user()->name && !empty($this->user->phone) )
```

Here, I have to check condition for the city, name, phone and lot's of other properties, is there a way to add a shortcut like this

```
if(!empty($this->user()->{city,name,phone})
```

Comment: I don't know what user is, but it would be a _bit_ shorter to use `$user = $this->user();` in the previous line. Then you'd use `$user->city   $user->name`.

Comment: Btw, I don't think [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) takes more than one argument. Check your parentheses, if necessary.

Comment: @FirstOne that's not the point, I can do that, but I still have to check it multiple time like `$user->city` and again `$user->name`

Comment: `empty` is just an example, I am looking for a way to call those object operator easily, like `$user->{city,name,phone}`

Comment: That's why I didn't post an answer, just commented about it.

Comment: How _would_ that work? You ask for city, name and phone and get what?

Comment: Why negative votes though, I am only asking if it's possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the exact thing you're trying to do really isn't possible. The closest thing I can think of is to define an array of properties and check them in a loop.

```
$required = ['city', 'name', 'phone', 'lots', 'of', 'other', 'properties'];

$complete = true;
foreach ($required as $property) {
    if (empty($this->user()->$property)) {
        $complete = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This can help to avoid a giant complex `if` condition like that; instead you just check

```
if ($complete) ...
```

after the loop.

It seems like the specific thing you're trying to do with this is entity validation. If you use one of the various PHP frameworks, there are utilities that can make this easier for you. You can just add a `required` annotation to the property or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I am using Laravel, is there any solution for laravel

Comment: @Cowgirl - [Laravel has a very useful validation handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation)

Comment: @MarkBaker how is that useful in my context?

Comment: It allows you to define rules for your model properties, then use a simple validation call to see if those rules have been met

Comment: @Cowgirl I was about to paste the same link Mark just did. It's definitely the way I'd prefer to do it if I was using Laravel. I think validation isn't usually a one-liner kind of thing. You'll likely discover at some point that you need to validate other things besides just whether or not something is blank, and the validator makes it easy to do all of that at once.

Comment: Thanks, I will check into that, there are definitely lots of things I need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in for that sort of multiple-field check. Depending on the values in your variables and what you consider to be empty, you might be able to just concatenate all the fields together and check for the emptiness of that:

```
if (empty($user->city . $user->name . $user->phone)) {
    // all fields are empty
} else {
    // at least one field is not empty
}
```

... but that's rather... ugly.

> and lot's of other properties,

Well, that's what loops are for. I'd simply write a method to verify that you have the required fields. Something like this maybe:

```
class User
{

    const REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'city', 'state'];

    public function hasRequiredFields(): bool
    {
        foreach (self::REQUIRED_FIELDS as $field) {
            if (empty($this->$field)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Then you can just do:

```
if ($user->hasRequiredFields()) {
    ...
}
```

If your user object already has all the required fields defined as public properties, then you can just iterate over the object itself to get them:

```
class User
{

    public $name;
    public $city;
    public $state;

    public function hasRequiredFields(): bool
    {
        foreach ($this as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems flawed. Concatenating `0` (which is considered empty) with another `0` is `00`, not empty anymore.

Comment: Not to mention that concatenation removes the possibility to use `OR`.

Comment: True -- depends what's in the vars and what OP considers empty. Like I said, it's rather ugly.

Comment: This adds a certain complexity in my code, while my main aim is to make it easier to read, and write less code

Comment: Heh well the ability to use `OR` wasn't in the spec. :)

Comment: I am looking for one-liners

Comment: `$user->hasRequiredFields()` is as easy to read as you're going to get. Putting the code in a method makes it reusable. If you need to perform the check in more than one location, are you going to cut-and-paste a giant `if` statement to each? See [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is no function to test this you have to write your own custom function for example check given entries in array is blank or not
(All entries send to it are mendatory)

```
function checkEmpty($arr)
{
  foreach($arr as $value)
  {
    if(empty(trim($value)))
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
$arr = array('name'=>'nilesh','age'=>' ');
if(checkEmpty($arr))
 echo "true part here";
else
 echo 'False Part Here';
```

Comment: I am looking for one-liners :P

Comment: I don't think it is possible with 1 line. If you wrote such function in a single file and used that file then it will be possible. use client side validations. but they can be break easily.